# How to create a sql-query for such situation?

Tags: mysql

How to make a SQL-query for getting titles only with their maximum rating from this table?
[SQL-table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/liSsk.png)

Comment: if you want help with SQL, you should provide the DDL to define the table and insert the relevant data,  and an example of the desired results.

Comment: _not_ as a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that this will work

```
SELECT title, MAX(stars) FROM table GROUP BY title
```

Comment: Yeah, it really worked! Thank you! I thought that query should be more complicated for it :)

Comment: awesome. yes i know what you mean